# Mongo backup - performance

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm going to run schedule backup for my MongoDB server base on [this opensource script](http://github.com/micahwedemeyer/automongobackup).

My data is about 10GB (and counting) and back it up taking time, my question is - is that backup operation actually blocking the database or will make the server slow to not serve the applications using it? or that Mongo backup is smart enough to do that in background without harm the service?

Do anyone have this such experience?

TU.

Comment: If your server is taking a alot of load, I'd suggest setting up replica-set  and instead of backing up Primary, backup secondary. This will not slow down your server and hurt applications.

Comment: ok, and first time replication can also takes lot of resources?

Comment: well, it needs to transfer and insert 10Gb worth of data...

Comment: that script uses `mongodump` as the workhorse, so take a look at its [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: Yes, it will take some time but will not consume alot of resources as compared to taking backup. but will make your life easier in future.